# How to use setfill() in <iomanip> more fluently?

Tags: c++, iomanip

Today, I learned about `setfill()` and other methods in `#include<iomanip>`, so I have a practice with using `#include<iomanip>`.

I want to print this on the console:

```
+-------------------------+         
|    Iomanip Examples     |  
+-------------------------+
```

So I wrote this code:

```
cout << '+' << setfill('-') << setw(25) << '+' << endl;
cout << setw(26) << internal << "Iomanip Examples" << endl;
cout << '+' << setfill('-') << setw(25) << '+' << endl;
```

but my console printed this:

```
+---------------------------+     //It's okay.  
------Iomanip Examples           //nope..  
+---------------------------+
```

I think when I use `setfill('-')`, the output stream is filled with `'-'` character in the empty spaces.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

you again need to use `setfill(' ')` for the second line as in your case.
once we use `setfill()` it will set for all-time in program where we use `setw()`.

Comment: Thx. And now I realize my problem. I thought 'internal' keyword helps string arranged in the middle of output stream, but it isn't.

Comment: Example) std::cout << setw(6) << internal << -23 << std::endl; // output: |-   23|

Comment: @Samuel per [this reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/left): “*Modifies the default positioning of the fill characters. `left` and `right` apply to any output, **`internal` applies to integer, floating-point, and monetary output**.*” So it has no effect in your example.